# How to solve this ode equation where one of the inputs has some delay and equation has written in matrix form in MATLAB ode45?

Tags: matlab, ode

I have an ode equation in matrix form.

`A=[ -0.1078 0 0 0 -10 0; 0 -0.0898 0 0 0 -8.3333; 0 0 -0.2352 0 10 0; 0 0 0 -0.196 0 8.3333; 1 0 -1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 -1 0 0];` and `B=[0.3313 0 -8.9335 0; 0 0.2761 0 -7.4446; 0 0 3.7249 0;0 0 0 3.104; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0];`. `C=[ 0 0 1.4206 1.4206 0 0]` and `D= [0 0 -15 -15]`.  `x=[x1;x2;x3;x4;x5;x6];` `u=[u1;u2;f1;f2];`, where u1=0.045, u2=0.038 in which u1 is acting at t=0 and u2 will act after 20 seconds before that it is 0 (i.e. `if t<=20 u2=0; else u2=0.038;)` and `f1=0; f2=0;`. `xdot=[x1dot;x2dot;x3dot;x4dot;x5dot;x6dot];`
Initial conditions is `x0=[0 0 0 0 0 0]`, `Tspan=[0 40]`

Finally the ode is
`dx=A*x + B*u` and output equation is `y= C*x + D*u`.

How to solve this ode equation where one input u2 has some delay in MATLAB ode45?

Comment: What is preventing you to define `u2` exactly as you have written it? It is not really a delay as in delay-differential equations, but a ramp function with its jump at a certain time.

Comment: @Lutz Lehman I didn't say it is a delay- differential equation. I said that delay in input. In delay differential delay is in state mainly. Other thing is that for small order system I write input equation using ```for``` loop. Like ```u1=v(1);  if t <= 70   u(2)=0; else u2=v(2); end``` in function file but for large matrix system it is very difficult.

Comment: But then you would have an organized data source for the jump times, so that you could evaluate them in a loop. If you have more structure in these events, the "engine" to parse and apply the list of events gets a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Run your system for 20 seconds with u2=0. Then take that result as initial conditions for a new run with u2=0.038

Comment: In actual I have 19 input have different delays, so it is very difficult to run the program in this way. In question I  considered only one delay input system. If I get for this then I will generalize it for 'n' delay input system.